# JavaScriptEngineSwitcher loading resource javascript file failing

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a .NET 8 Core C# MVC project to provide the content as website and a class library to host the logic.

I'm trying to run ua-parser-js through JavaScriptEngineSwitcher as I couldnt find a C# based project like this which was recently updated.

I installed the nuget packages to my class library and added the JsEngineSwitcher to the available services in my MVC projects Program.cs file.

```
builder.Services.AddJsEngineSwitcher(options =>
{
    options.AllowCurrentProperty = false;
    options.DefaultEngineName = JintJsEngine.EngineName;
}).AddJint();
```

In my Controller I load the injected Service as below

```
var jsEngineSwitcher = _serviceProvider.GetService<IJsEngineSwitcher>();
var engine = jsEngineSwitcher.CreateDefaultEngine();
```

I'm passing the UA and the engine to my class library method where I am trying to load the JS file. The JS file is added as a embedded ressource in the root folder of the class library.

```
engine.ExecuteResource("<class library name>.ua-parser.min.js", typeof(Program).Assembly);
```

Unfortunately this fails with

`System.NullReferenceException: 'Resource with name '<class library name>.ua-parser.min.js' is null.'`

I checked if the JS file is really exiting as a ressource by below code, and it does have ".ua-parser.min.js"

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceNames();
```

The sample projects in the [github repo](https://github.com/Taritsyn/JavaScriptEngineSwitcher) seem not to load any JS and I wasn't able to find a recent example [except this](https://andrewlock.net/running-javascript-in-a-dotnet-app-with-javascriptengineswitcher/).

Anyone having an idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, instead of

```
engine.ExecuteResource("<class library name>.ua-parser.min.js", typeof(Program).Assembly);
```

I had to use

```
engine.ExecuteResource("<class library name>.ua-parser.min.js", typeof(<class library name here>).Assembly);
```